# Workbox background sync not storing in mysql database

Tags: mysql, workbox, background-sync

I can get the sync to work and clear out the IndexedDB queue but the data is not being stored in my mysql database. Is there something I am missing?

My service worker:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.1/workbox-sw.js');

// This is the "Offline copy of assets" service worker

const CACHE = "pwabuilder-offline";
const SYNC = "bgSync"
const QUEUE_NAME = "bgSyncQueue";


self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('/*'),
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
      cacheName: CACHE
    })
);

const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.BackgroundSyncPlugin(QUEUE_NAME, {
    maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours (specified in minutes)
  });

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https:\/\/domain.com\/[a-zA-Z]+\/journal'),
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out background sync doesn't like to be tested within a browser. Tried it from my phone via the installed app and it works fine.